# Format Date with culture in Razor @Html.EditFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

MVC 4, C#.

In my razor view I have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ActionObject.StartDate)
```

Which is annotated in my model with:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

In the view, it is set like so, with date picker:

[image: date]

Notice how it is mm/dd/yyyy. How can I change this dynamically based on the user? The user can set there culture to whatever they want.

Normally I can do:

```
.ToString("d", culture)
```

Where culture is set dynamically. But this doesn't work for @Html.Editfor.

Comment: Is this the native Chrome datepicker? If so, it's based on the culture of your pc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This **datepicker** is the native representation for HTML 5 **input type date** in Google Chrome. You can't change this format. The display format comes from user Culture / Localization config in his OS.

If you want to format this as you want, remove the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`, rendering a default **input field** and then use a **JQuery UI DatePicker** or another one to render a better date field.