# Issue with jQuery datepicker and client side validation for dates in ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is an Asp.net MVC application. I have installed packages jQuery.alidation.Globalize and jQuery.UI.i18n and have set fixed culture "es-PY" in web.config

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="es" culture="es-PY" />
```

I have set this culture also for jQuery validations:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Globalize.culture('es-PY');
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $("input[type='date']").datepicker();
});
```

Also i have decorated Dates properties as follow in my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
```

I'm facing problems with displaying the jQuery datepicker, as you can see from the image i get not one, but two dropdown calendars, apart from that in the text input the value is seted to dd/mm/aaaa, it should be rendered with the Fecha property. When  i try to select a date from the calendar the client validation fails which is disconcerting me because es-PY culture accept dd/MM/yyyy date format.

So my question actually are two in one: Why i am getting two calendars for the inputbox and what else should i do to get the date pass validation in client browser?

[image]

Comment: Did you use `EditorFor`? If you have an email control template, it will use that as the editor, and then you applied another using the datepicker plugin.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes I use editor for, I dont get you when you say an email control template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format Date with culture in Razor @Html.EditFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283557/format-date-with-culture-in-razor-html-editfor)

Comment: @Fals, following the directives from the link you suggest as duplicated, the calendar from the right is gone in Firefox but not in Chrome which keeps displaying dd/mm/yyyy in the input box.

Comment: @Elio.Batista If you want to use the datepicker plugin, change `EditorFor` to `TextBoxFor` - otherwise the Razor engine will create a `<input type="date" />` element, and then it's up to the browser to decide what to do.

Comment: @Elio.Batista Sorry, the "email" bit was me not paying attention to what I was typing; that should have read "a date control template". For instance, I use Telerik UI controls, and one of the things they add is an EditorTemplate folder in Shared. That means a `DateTime` property triggers the Razor engine to use Telerik's Date.cshtml template when using `EditorFor`.

Comment: @TiesonT. you were right . I got rid of the Chrome's  builtin calendar and the date is validated just fine. Please post your last comment in the answers section so I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the datepicker plugin, change `EditorFor` to `TextBoxFor` - otherwise the Razor engine will create a `<input type="date" />` element, and then it's up to the browser to decide what to do.

For instance, I use Telerik UI controls, and one of the things they add is an `EditorTemplate` folder in `Shared`. That means a `DateTime` property triggers the Razor engine to use Telerik's `DateTime.cshtml` or `Date.cshtml` (depending on the data-annotated type) template when using `EditorFor`.

The same would be true if you had any property that mapped to the name of an editor template.